# laravel, how to get the value of 3 options so if y then yes if n then no if r then rejected

Tags: php, laravel

in simple way I have this code which reads the result of two options but what if I want them to be 3

I have 3 chars: `y`, `n` and `r`

```
y = yes
n = not yet
r = rejected
```

How can I print the last alternative?

```
{{ ($item->confirmed =='y')?"Yes":"Not Yet" }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a switch in the blade syntax instead, this is available from Laravel 5.5

```
@switch($item->confirmed)
    @case('y')
        Yes
        @break

    @case('n')
        Not yet
        @break

    @default
        Rejected
@endswitch
```

If you are running a version without the `switch` directive, you can use a normal `if`.

```
@if ($item->confirmed == 'y')
    Yes
@elseif ($item->confirmed == 'n')
    Not yet
@else
    Rejected
@endif
```

You *can* also chain the ternary operators, but its not as pretty. I would recommend going for either of the two above. This can easily be more difficult to read, particularly if you add more conditions - its better to use a switch.

```
{{ ($item->confirmed == 'y') ? "Yes" : ($item->confirmed == 'n' ? "Not Yet" : 'Rejected') }}
```